# Finding potential energy of a solid hemisphere on top of another solid hemisphere

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, homework-and-exercises

> A solid hemisphere with radius $b$ has its flat surface glued to a
>   horizontal table. Another solid hemisphere with radius $a$ rests on top
>   of the hemisphere of radius $b$ so that the curved surfaces in contact.
>   The surfaces of hemispheres are rough, meaning no slipping occurs
>   between them. Both hemispheres have uniform mass distributons. Two
>   objects are said to be in equilibrium when the top one is upside down
>   - that is, with its flat surface parallel to the table but above it. Show that the equilibrium position is stable if $a<3b/5$.

I was thinking about using gravitational potential energy (based on center of mass) to solve the problem and using $r\omega =v$. But there seems to be no way out of here, because the onily thing gravitational potential energy wold depend on would be the $y$-coordinate part where $-y$ is direction of gravity.

Would there be a way to solve this problem with setting up potential energy?

Comment: Do you have a picture? I don't understand the setup.

Answer (score 1):

I would attack this problem this way:

1. Locate the center of gravity of the upper hemisphere;  specifically determine how far up the central radius the CofG lies
2. Assume the upper sphere rotates ("wobbles") through an angle $\theta$;  find the new point of contact between the upper and lower hemispheres in terms of $\theta$
3. From these new points of contacts, find the new height for the center of gravity in terms of $\theta$
4. Find the derivative of this height with respect to $\theta$
5. Find the conditions relating $a$ and $b$ so that in the limit of $\theta=0$, this derivative is positive.